# Clone & Append All Links to Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the "Clone All" button to Clone & Append each individual link to the #container.

But when you click on the button right now, it just makes 3 clones of the first link in the document (www.google.com) and skips the two others (www.facebook.com & www.youtube.com).

I'm pretty sure I need to use an array. I've tried to store the a class ('.link') in an array, and I tried to use the each() method — but I can't make it work :-/

**CodePen:** http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/eZgbKq/

**jQuery:**

```
var links = $('.link');
var hrefs = $(links).attr('href'); // grab a href attribute from links
var cloneAllLinks = $('.btn-clone-all-links');

$(cloneAllLinks).on('click', function(event) {

  $(links).clone().text(hrefs).append('<li></li>').appendTo('#container');

});
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store each individual href attribute value in an array:

```
var linkArray = $('.link').map(function(index, link) { return $(link).attr('href'); });
```

You can then loop over this array, writing out each item to the #container div:

```
$(cloneAllLinks).on('click', function(event) {
    $.each(linkArray, function(index, val){
        var linkTemplate = '<li>' + val + '</li>' 
        $('#container').append(linkTemplate);
    })
});
```

See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZrzba

Comment: Thanks mark_c, very helpful with the array! But now the urls in #container have their link tag stripped, how do I keep the a href around the urls — like they are in my CodePen? I don't see where in your code they are removed..

Comment: thanks, but I think you meant `"<li><a href='"+val+"'>"+val+"</a></li>"` , anyways that's what I did and it works. What you wrote will output wrong HTML `<a href="www.google.com&lt;/a">www.google.com</a>` 
Anyways, appreciate your help, learned a lot from your code!

Comment: @capax, Yeah sorry, was doing it from memory whilst at work. Shows the importance of proper testing! Glad you got it working.